# Disable External Pingacks on WordPress Posts and Only Allow 'Self Pings'

Tags: php, plugin-development, posts, functions, pingbacks

I use wordpress for my Social Media site. WordPress Pings allow other blog posts to appear in comments when they link to us.

I want to limit it to only blog posts created on my own site. Basically I only want SELF-PINGS/Trackbacks.

If Other site tries to send ping reject it then and their, but if my own site https://milyin.com's post tries to send a ping readily accept it and show it in comment section.

I tried, **wp-admin** -> **discussion** -> (unselect) **Allow links from other blog posts.**

But that disables internal Pings too.
Secondly My authors are able to turn on/off the pingbacks for each post. So, many of the posts still recieve external pings.

Here's a screenshot of the same: **https://snipboard.io/8lVIrE.jpg**

I tried to do some code.

I found a tutorial from **[How Disable Self Pingbacks in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-disable-self-pingbacks-in-wordpress/)**

And I tried to modify it to fit my needs

```
function SelfPing( &$links ) {
    $Home = get_option( 'home' );
    foreach ( $links as $l => $link ){
        if ( strpos( $link, $Home )  === false){
            unset($links[$l]);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_ping', 'SelfPing' );
```

However this didn't solve the purpose.

I still recieve pings from all sorts of sites, on my posts, as majority of my authors manually turn on Pings.

So How can I have only self pings, and remove external pings, even when my authors manually turn on pings for all posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to receive only linkbacks from your own WordPress site, then try both of these:

But if you want to allow all that were sent as *trackbacks* (where the comment type is `trackback`), then just ignore the second snippet below, which I added because in default/core themes like Twenty Twenty-One, both pingbacks and trackbacks would each appear as a "Pingback" in the post's comments section.

1. This uses the [`xmlrpc_call` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/xmlrpc_call/) to disable [pingbacks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/introduction-to-blogging/#pingbacks) sent via the XML-RPC method:

   ```php
   add_action( 'xmlrpc_call', 'disallow_external_xmlrpc_pingback', 10, 3 );
   function disallow_external_xmlrpc_pingback( $name, $args, $server ) {
       if ( 'pingback.ping' == $name && false === strpos( $args[0], home_url() ) ) {
           // Exit with a proper error.
           $server->error( new IXR_Error( 0, 'Sorry, trackbacks from remote sites are not allowed.' ) );
       }
   }
   ```
2. This uses the [`pre_trackback_post` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_trackback_post/) to disable [trackbacks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/introduction-to-blogging/#trackbacks) sent via the standard HTTP POST method (i.e. not using XML-RPC):

   ```php
   add_action( 'pre_trackback_post', 'disallow_external_POST_trackback', 10, 2 );
   function disallow_external_POST_trackback( $tb_id, $tb_url ) {
       if ( false === strpos( $tb_url, home_url() ) ) {
           // Exit with a proper error.
           trackback_response( 1, 'Sorry, trackbacks from remote sites are not allowed.' );
       }
   }
   ```

And BTW, in the code in the question, `$home` is undefined and it should be `$Home` ( note the uppercase "H" and see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) which says, "*variable name is case-sensitive*" :) ).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about error in my question. I shall correct my question rn. Besides that I shall use your code and let you know soon

Comment: Take your time. And actually, I also made a slight mistake in my answer - the error message for the `xmlrpc_call` should actually be begin with "Sorry, **pingbacks** from".. sorry about that.

Comment: Hey... I just added 2-3 links on my site to check for Self Pings... Haven't recieved any Ping in past 1 hr. Was wondering how much time in general it takes to detect pings. And is their a way to manually make wordpress look for pings... (Again, I am not commenting on whether the code worked or not, just that I am curious)

Comment: Try changing the post status to Draft then to Publish, and wait for the pingbacks to come. I'm not exactly sure of the time, though, but it shouldn't be too long. (Edit: I mean, the status of the post with the internal links.)

Comment: Magic. Worked like charm... Got the self ping in like 5 seconds... Allow me few hours to ensure that external pings are ignored, before marking it as the answer

Comment: It's not exactly a magic.. because pingbacks are processed when the post is published, for the 1st time and the 2nd, 3rd, etc. times. But anyway, as I said before, take your time (in testing), and hopefully my code works for you..

Comment: Hey, i think it worked. I might trouble you again, if it troubles.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't make any other use of XMLRPC service in WordPress than the pingbacks/trackbacks, you could try limiting requests to `xmlrpc.php` file only for requests from your own server by adding this to your `.htaccess` file

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

This would work only if your webserver is Apache and it's configured to read local `.htaccess` files of overriding it's main configuration. Nginx, Litespeed and others don't use `.htaccess` files whatsoever, so no point in trying this with them.

Edit:

If you are using `xmlrpc.php` for other stuff too, you could use the `xmlrpc_call` hook in order to check if the call is a pingback and if it's from the right address (localhost). Here's how it should look (in theory):

```
add_action( 'xmlrpc_call', 'limit_to_local_pingbacks', 10, 3 );
function limit_to_local_pingbacks( string $type_of_call, array|string $args, wp_xmlrpc_server $server ) {
    if ( 'pingback.ping' !== $type_of_call ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( '127.0.0.1' !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) {
        wp_die();
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh that could have been a good approach, however I use XMLRPC for other works on my site too... Regardles thank you for putting in the effort in trying to helpl me.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, have a look at the edit I did on my solution. Perhaps this would work better for you?

Comment: Thanks for supporting, I would like to test it out for somtime... Just to see that Self Pings work and cross pings are stopped (as I am not familiar with XMLRPC side of WP)... Hopefully it works... Will report/mark it corrrect after testin

Comment: Hey @Vlood, I checked and unfortunately it doesn't really work. It's a server error when ever XML RPC is used...  `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function limit_to_local_pingbacks(), 1 passed in` [file name] `and exactly 3 expected.` This comes whenever apps like Zapier and IFTTT use the XMLRPC...

Just so you know, I am running PHP 8, which has some differences in Type declarations so I am using this `function limit_to_local_pingbacks( $type_of_call, $args, $server )` at the start of function

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, I'm out of office for the next couple of days, but after that I'll give this a spin myself, as I'm curious to see if and how it would work in practice.

Comment: @AdityaArgawal, to get rid of that error, you actually just needed to set the *fourth* parameter for `add_action()` to `3` because the hook callback is expecting to receive three parameters; so, `add_action( 'xmlrpc_call', 'limit_to_local_pingbacks', 10, 3);`.